# Remove spaces in string under quotation in Notepad++ using RegEx

Tags: regex, notepad++

Suppose I have these strings:

```
'akshay  ' ,
'  ankur'
```

I want to remove trailing and leading spaces present under quotation mark like this:
'akshay',
'ankur'

How can I achieve this in Notepad++ using RegEX?

Comment: Why do you need RegEx for simple find and replace?

Comment: @PankajJaju: because the number of spaces is variable.

Comment: Although he should use RegEx, he didn't provide Q with any attempts. @PankajJaju

Comment: yes,the number of spaces is variable. If i find for each space,it will take so much time. In this case we have to search many times.

Comment: @ Casimir et Hippolyte,@PankajJaju: I have tried below RegExp
 \s(?!(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$     but showing Invalid exp.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to find: `'(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)'` and this  to replace: `'\2'`.

Comment: Thanks @VMRuiz..working for me to remove spaces.
Could you please help me to count all the spaces. By using your RegExp when i click on 'count' button, it is counting all the strings whether they have spaces or not.

Answer (score 0):

Find this regexp: **(^')\s+(\w+)\s*(')|(^')\s*(\w+)\s+(')**
Replace with : **\1\2\3\4\5\6**

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you please help me to count all the spaces. By using your RegExp when i click on 'count' button, it is counting all the strings whether they have spaces or not.

Comment: Thanku so much...almost working..
I saw from other blogs,there was a RegExp      \s(?!(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$ to count  number of spaces.I noted from there but by mistake i forgot something in this Exp. Can you please find out what is the error in this Exp?

Answer (score 0):

All the RegExp given above solve my problem in a better way. I appreciate to all who helped me to solve this problem. Thank you everyone.

Here i am going to add a RegExp given below which can be used to count total number of spaces inside single quotation. It can be used to remove all spaces also.

Find-->  \s(?!(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)  and ReplaceWith-->Nothing to do(leave blank) then click 'ReplaceAll'.